# How do I add custom filesystem to list for the Window's Format Data dialog?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, filesystems, wdk, minifilter

I would like to add a file system to the list of file systems in the Window's Format Data dialog.

[image]

Where is this data populated from? I'm guessing it's enumerated from the existing Installable File Systems (drivers, filters, minifilters)?

What I'm trying to do is create a custom file system that is basically identical to NTFS but has a very small difference. I was wondering if I could create an IFS driver/filter/minifilter that would allow me to piggyback on the existing NTFS driver (like a passthrough but letting it pass through to a specific file system driver instead of just falling to the next avaialble) and allow me to list it in the format data dialog box along with calling my format function which would call the underlying NTFS format function.

I'm not sure if this is possible or how it would be done. I'm basically looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you mind sharing what that 'very small difference' is ?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit When A drive is formatted in the "new FS" it will format it as NTFS but change 2 bytes within the first 512 bytes of the drive, other than that the entire drive will be NTFS. I would also like to be able to tell the NTFS driver that even though those 2 bytes are different, it's still readable by the NTFS driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would write an IFS or [Installable File System Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Those drivers are normally written as mini-driver, but since you want to manipulate the NTFS file system, it should be enough to write a [File System Filter Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548202(v=vs.85).aspx).

An example of such a IFS driver is this [Ext2 file system driver](http://www.fs-driver.org/download.html).

Comment: Writing a mini-driver that manipulates NTFS would allow me to list it as a new file system in the format drive dialog box in the file system drop down?

Comment: This is what I understand: an **IFS driver** will let you create a complete new FS that will show up in the list. But I don't think you can then still use the existing NTFS implementation. A **filter driver**, on the other hand, is installed for a certain FS or volume and will let you manipulate the existing NTFS implementation but will not add a new FS to the list.